# Proof of Convergence in Distribution and Limsup

Tags: probability-distributions, limsup-and-liminf

I'm currently using 'Adventure in Stochastic Processes' for self-study. Here's [the link](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=YGjTl8iX-HsC&lpg=PR9&ots=7WFGZt-2rP&dq=adventures%20of%20stochastic%20process&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q&f=false). This is the part I don't understand:

Letting $\left[n\rightarrow \infty\right]$, we get $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mid P_n(s)-P_o(s)) \mid \leq \epsilon$.

I have never learned about limsup, so I'm confused what this means. Why not just use limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not just use limit?

Because, as is often the case, one does not know yet whether a limit exists. [Limsups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) always exist hence they are useful to show that limits exist and to determine them.

To wit, a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $\ell$ if and only if $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|x_n-\ell|=0$ if and only if, for every $\varepsilon\gt0$, $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}|x_n-\ell|\leqslant\varepsilon$.